# How can I get the size of a leveldb dataset using Python?

Tags: leveldb, caffe2

is there a function or an efficient way to get the size of a leveldb dataset using python? I am working with big datasets which contain more than 400,000 elements.

I am using Caffe2 for deep learning.

Thanks in advance.